# how to deploy my express (node) + vue app on VPS-hosting with Hestia CP?

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, vps

I want to deploy my app (node, vue, mysql) on VPS with Hestia CP. I already have a domain and want my app to work with it. How to do it? Read that nginx is required but didn't get clearly how to use it.

app.js (entry)

```js
    import express, { urlencoded } from "express";

    import path from "path";

    import routes from "./routes/router.js"

    const __dirname = path.resolve();
    const router = express.Router();
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.port ?? 5000;


    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")));
    app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css"));
    app.use(routes)

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname, "views"));

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`);
    });
```

I tried to use `node app` (before that provided files on hosting via file manager). Before depolying I used to launch my app with `nodemon` or `node app`.